# big values for strtotime()

Tags: php, time, strtotime, seconds

I tried

echo strtotime('129:00');

but it will have an empty output.

This
echo strtotime('03:00');

will have 1288339200 as the output.

I guess strtotime() won't accept huge values?? What's the alternative for strtotime() that will accept 129:00.

Comment: what is 129:00 suppose to mean?

Answer (score 3):

The alternative is to give `strtotime()` a time that actually means something. I know of no clocks that go up to 129 o'clock myself.

That's not to say there aren't any but I'm pretty old and I've traveled a bit. I'm sure I would have noticed something like this :-)

See the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), which state:

> The function expects to be given a string containing a US English date format

and end up pointing you [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php) for valid time formats.

Comment: 129 o'clock would be 9am five days later, according to [Japanese thinking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_by_country#Japan). There are no 144+ hour wall clocks here either though. ;)

Answer (score 2):

`strtotime` parses a date or a time (of the day, 24h clock) into UNIX timestamps. `129:00` is neither a date nor a time, so it returns `false`. It's not "too big", it's simply invalid input.